# trying to load capybara gem and getting an error of "extconf failed, exit code 1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qt4, capybara, bundle, homebrew

I am to set my development environment to work on [this open source project](https://github.com/AgileVentures/WebsiteOne).

Going through the set up instructions I tried to run `bundle install` and got this error

```
Fetching capybara-webkit 1.14.0
Installing capybara-webkit 1.14.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/iloveburningman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0
...
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/iloveburningman/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/iloveburningman/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.14.0), and Bundler 
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.14.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then tried to setup capybara manually with `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.14.0'` and got essentially the same response of

extconf failed, exit code 1

```
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/iloveburningman/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.3.1/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/iloveburningman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/gem_make.out
```

I have also tried updating my macOs to high sierra and reinstalling homebrew

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the requisite packages installed to build it.  Check the `gem_make.out` file to see what the actual errors are.

Comment: Also note, this isn't the Capybara gem, it's the capybara-webkit gem which is a driver which can be used with Capybara

Comment: And how is this related to the [qt4] tag?